# Explorer's search button not working

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

I have a PC that is running XP and the Search button (in explorer) it's not working. When I click it, it does nothing.

Any idea on how to fix this?

[Update]
On my account it works (admin) and on another user (limited) it's not working. I don't want to re-create the user, just want to find the reg key or rule and fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a policy **[NoFind](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938268.aspx)** under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer, I deleted it and now it works fine

Comment: This worked for me. It may actually be a policy being pushed out by the domain, but I won't know until the user logs back in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is relevant, but this link shows how to disable search button from the registry
http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/845/
May be there are some other useful keys in that registry hive
Also see this one as well, but I think it might for Windows 7 (not quite sure)
http://www.lee.org/blog/2009/04/25/how-to-disable-windows-search-when-searching-windows-explorer/

Comment: there is no such key, but i'm searching...

Comment: I know there won't be, I just meant there may be some relevant keys at that area

Comment: Anyway, go to group policy editor (Start > Run > gpedit.msc) > User configuration > administrative templates > windows components> windows explorer > disable search button in windows explorer. This is probably be 'not configured'. try enabling this option, restarting, then disabling and see if that works

Comment: you gave me an idea where to look, so i'm gonna mark your answer

Answer (score 0):

it could be a setting in the group policy. Run the editor, and look for permessions for search.